# What is the meaning of "zone" in copyWithZone:?

Tags: cocoa, nscopying

I was going through "Pro. Objective-C Design Patterns for iOS" by Chung and found

`_sharedSinglton = [[super allocWithZone: NULL] init];`

I looked in Apple's documentation for [NSCopying](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) as well, but can't really understand what a ZONE really means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSZone` is obsolete now, but back in the NEXTSTEP days, `NSZone` was an attempt to bring the concept of "malloc zones" into Cocoa. Here are some docs that described how it worked when it was enabled: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZone

Comment: so, how it's different to specify `zone` as `NULL` and `Default`?

Comment: I just looked up the book and quote on Google. I think the reason they use `-allocWithZone:` in this case is that their singleton pattern already overrode `-alloc`, and they wanted an easy way to avoid their `-alloc` override. `-allocWithZone:` dodges the override (since they never overrode that method) but doesn't change any behavior compared to a normal `-alloc` because zones are obsolete and don't do anything. Basically, this is a trick to dodge their own override of `-alloc` in an easy way, and the zone part is irrelevant.

Comment: thanks @StilesCrisis for the explanation; so, can we relate `Zone` as an `autorelease` pool (without autorelease functionality)?